# Generating random correlation coefficients (Pearson $r$)

Tags: r, probability, distributions, correlation, density-function

I'm trying generate some random correlation coefficients ($CC$) using the [Fisher's $z$ transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation). An `R` implementation is shown below.

However, it looks like the generated $CC$s can go beyond the $[-1, +1]$ limits that $CC$ can take.

I was wondering if this behavior is due to the small sample size I used here (i.e., $N = 10$)?

Is there a more accurate way to generate random correlation coefficients (I appreciate an `R` demonstration)?

```
rcor <- function(n, mean = 0, N){
  rnorm(n = n, mean = atanh(mean), sd = 1/sqrt(N - 3))
}
set.seed(0)
plot(density(rcor(n = 1e6, N = 10)), zero.line = F)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you need the backtransformation?

Comment: Is a 'random correlation coefficient' here just a random number between -1 and 1? If so, you could sample from any distribution whose support is $[-1, 1]$ and more information would be needed to answer the question--i.e. what distribution do you want? (otherwise there's [this](https://i.imgur.com/uR4WuQ0.gif))

Comment: @Aaron, Thanks! is the follwoing correct?: `rcor <- function(n, mean = 0, N){ ;
  tanh(rnorm(n = n, mean = atanh(mean), sd = 1/sqrt(N - 3)));
}`

Comment: @morouzian: From memory, yes, I think so.

Comment: @user20160: No, not just any random number between -1 and 1; they want to simulate the distribution of the correlation coefficient from a sample size N using Fisher's z-transformation.

Comment: @Aaron, thanks. so i guess the prob. dens. fun. should be: `dcor <- function(x, mean = 0, N){
  
  dnorm(x, mean = atanh(mean), sd = 1/sqrt(N - 3))
}`

Comment: You should look at the minima and maxima of the actual distribution. I have sometimes noticed problems like this with R plotting densities that are bounded but the plot looks unbounded.